# Overloading operator<< for a nested private class possible?

Tags: c++, nested, operator-overloading, nested-class

How one can overload an operator<< for a nested private class like this one?

```
class outer {
  private:
    class nested {
       friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const nested& a);
    };
  // ...
};
```

When trying outside of outer class compiler complains about privacy:

```
error: ‘class outer::nested’ is private
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You could make the `operator<<` a friend of `outer` as well.  Or you
could implement it completely `inline` in `nested`, e.g.:

```
class Outer
{
    class Inner
    {
        friend std::ostream& 
        operator<<( std::ostream& dest, Inner const& obj )
        {
            obj.print( dest );
            return dest;
        }
        //  ...
        //  don't forget to define print (which needn't be inline)
    };
    //  ...
};
```

Comment: and the print function should be a `const` member function. If it is `std::ostream& print(std::ostream &out) const`, then `operator<<` can be just one line : `return obj.print(dest);`.

Comment: Why does std:ostream need to be a friend of Inner?

Comment: Because you can't define it in `Inner` otherwise.  (And if it's not defined in `Inner`, you have the problem that it can't access `Inner`, because `Inner` is a private member of `Outer`.)

Comment: @Mordachai - It's basically an inline free-function (i.e. not a member function) definition inside a class. The thing that's a friend isn't `std::ostream`, it's `operator<<( std::ostream& dest, Inner const& obj )`. The `std::ostream &` is just the return type of the function.

Answer (score 10):

if you want the same thing in two different file (hh, cpp) you have to friend two time the function as follow:

hh:

```
// file.hh
class Outer
{
    class Inner
    {
        friend std::ostream& operator<<( std::ostream& dest, Inner const& obj );
        // ...
    };

    friend std::ostream& operator<<( std::ostream& dest, Outer::Inner const& obj );
    //  ...
};
```

cpp:

```
// file.cpp:
#include "file.hh"

std::ostream    &operator<<( std::ostream& dest, Outer::Inner const& obj )
{
    return dest;
}
```