# How to properly overload the operator<< for a class with a collection of nested private classes?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, inner-classes

I'd like to implement `operator<<` for my templated class so that it can print all the elements it contains to the given `std::ostream&`. The issue is that I can't seem to get it to recognize the function that I've defined.

The error I get is

```
error: no match for 'operator<<' (operand types are 'std::ostream {aka std::basic_ostream<char>}' and 'Outer<int>::Inner')
         os << inner << ", ";
         ~~~^~~~~~~~
```

Ideally I'd like not to have the function defined inline, but I can't even get it to work inline. In the code below you can see that I've commented out my attempt at defining it outside the class declaration. It produces the same error as above.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8082190/4714742) recommends making the operator a friend of the class. I've done that every way I can think of and it still doesn't work.

The code:

```
#include <iostream>

template<class T>
class Outer {
    class Inner {
        T item;
        template<class T_>
        friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const typename Outer<T_>::Inner& inner) {
            os << inner.item;
            return os;
        }
        template<class T_>
        friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Outer<T_> outer);
    };
    std::vector<Inner> inner_items;
    template<class T_>
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Outer<T_> outer);
    template<class T_>
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const typename Outer<T_>::Inner& bar);

};

/*template<class T>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const typename Outer<T>::Inner& bar) {
    os << inner.item;
    return os;
}*/

template<class T>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Outer<T> outer) {
    for (typename Outer<T>::Inner inner : outer.inner_items) {
        os << inner << ", ";
    }
    return os;
}


int main()
{
    Outer<int> outer;
    std::cout << outer;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need (neither want) to templetize in `Inner`, just use the type:

```
class Outer {
    class Inner {
        T item;
        friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Inner& inner) {
            os << inner.item;
            return os;
        }
        // ...
```

What you wrote above fails because you define a *free function* in `Outer<T>::Inner` which is `operator<<(..)`. The second parameter is `Outer<T_>::Inner` and the compiler cannot go from `Inner` to the type in which it was defined.

Comment: This works, but is it possible to define the function external to the class declaration?

Answer (score 2):

Do **not** make the output operator for the nested types templates:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

template<class T>
class Outer {
    class Inner {
        T item;
        friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, typename Outer<T>::Inner const& inner) {
            os << inner.item;
            return os;
        }
        friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Outer<T> outer);
    };
    template <typename T_>
    friend std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream&, Outer<T_> const&);
    std::vector<Inner> inner_items;
};

template<class T>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, Outer<T> const& outer) {
    for (typename Outer<T>::Inner const& inner : outer.inner_items) {
        os << inner << ", ";
    }
    return os;
}

int main()
{
    Outer<int> outer;
    std::cout << outer;
}
```

There are a few `const&` sprinkled and a necessary `friend` declaration added, too.

Comment: lorro's answer shows that you don't need `typename Outer<T>::` in the declaration of the operator inside `Inner`. Why do you include it? Is it superfluous, or does it change something?

Comment: @JonMcClung: First off, the qualification was in the original. Using it doesn't change anything but I generally [fully] qualify my names so I didn't feel a need to drop it.